# How to calculate percentage between two different columns in two different tables

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the percentage between two different tables.
Example
Table1 : Item_id,Item_cost,item_type

Sno: 100,500,100f

Table 2: Item_id,Item_desc,Item_cost
sno: 100,100f,doll,1000
Now I want to show the percentage between table1 and table2. Here we have 50% loss in the cost

I want to show the percentage if it is profit show like 120% if it is negative -50%

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also add the matching expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle**:
If I got your data right it would be something like here:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_1 AS
        (
            Select 100 "ITEM_ID", 500 "ITEM_COST", '100f' "ITEM_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ITEM_ID", 700 "ITEM_COST", '200f' "ITEM_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 102 "ITEM_ID", 1000 "ITEM_COST", '300f' "ITEM_TYPE" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 AS
        (
            Select 100 "ITEM_ID", 'doll 1' "ITEM_DESC", 1000 "ITEM_COST" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ITEM_ID", 'doll 2' "ITEM_DESC",  500 "ITEM_COST" From Dual Union All
            Select 102 "ITEM_ID", 'doll 3' "ITEM_DESC", 800 "ITEM_COST" From Dual 
        )
```

... then the query should be ...

```sql
Select
    t1.ITEM_ID, t1.ITEM_TYPE, t2.ITEM_DESC,
  To_Char((t1.ITEM_COST * 100 / t2.ITEM_COST) - 100) || '%' "PROFIT"
From
    tbl_1 t1
Inner Join 
    tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.ITEM_ID = t1.ITEM_ID)
/*  R e s u l t :
   ITEM_ID ITEM_TYPE ITEM_DESC PROFIT                              
---------- --------- --------- --------
       100 100f      doll 1    -50%    
       101 200f      doll 2    40%     
       102 300f      doll 3    25%     
*/
```

***Addition***:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a AS
        (
            Select 1 "ITEM_ID",  '100F' "ITEM_TYPE", 1000 "ITEM_COST", 614 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ITEM_ID",  '100G' "ITEM_TYPE",  500 "ITEM_COST", 614 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ITEM_ID",  '200A' "ITEM_TYPE",  300 "ITEM_COST", 615 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ITEM_ID",  '200B' "ITEM_TYPE",  499 "ITEM_COST", 615 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ITEM_ID",  '300A' "ITEM_TYPE",  100 "ITEM_COST", 616 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ITEM_ID",  '400A' "ITEM_TYPE",    0 "ITEM_COST", 414 "ITEM" From Dual             
        ),
    tbl_b AS
        (
            Select 1 "ITEM_ID",  '100F' "ITEM_TYPE",  500 "ITEM_COST", 614 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ITEM_ID",  '100G' "ITEM_TYPE",  450 "ITEM_COST", 614 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ITEM_ID",  '200A' "ITEM_TYPE",  650 "ITEM_COST", 615 "ITEM" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ITEM_ID",  '300A' "ITEM_TYPE",  111 "ITEM_COST", 616 "ITEM" From Dual 
        )
Select
    t1.ITEM_ID, t1.ITEM_TYPE, t1.ITEM,
    t1.ITEM_COST "COST_A",
    t2.ITEM_COST "COST_B",
    CASE WHEN Nvl(CASE WHEN t1.ITEM_COST != 0 And t2.ITEM_COST != 0 THEN  t2.ITEM_COST - t1.ITEM_COST END, 0) > 0
         THEN 'Profit'
         WHEN Nvl(CASE WHEN t1.ITEM_COST != 0 And t2.ITEM_COST != 0 THEN  t2.ITEM_COST - t1.ITEM_COST END, 0) < 0
         THEN 'Loss'
    ELSE 'None'
    END "PROFIT_OR_LOSS",
    --
    ABS(CASE WHEN t1.ITEM_COST != 0 And t2.ITEM_COST != 0 
            THEN  t2.ITEM_COST - t1.ITEM_COST  
        END) "PROFIT_OR_LOSS_RS", 
    --
    ABS(CASE WHEN t1.ITEM_COST != 0 And t2.ITEM_COST != 0 
            THEN  Round((t2.ITEM_COST * 100 / t1.ITEM_COST) - 100, 2)  
        END) "PROFIT_OR_LOSS_PCT"
From
    tbl_a t1
Inner Join 
    tbl_b t2 ON(t2.ITEM_ID = t1.ITEM_ID And t1.ITEM_TYPE = t2.ITEM_TYPE)
/*  R e s u l t :
   ITEM_ID ITEM_TYPE       ITEM     COST_A     COST_B PROFIT_OR_LOSS PROFIT_OR_LOSS_RS PROFIT_OR_LOSS_PCT
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ----------------- ------------------
         1 100F             614       1000        500 Loss                         500                 50 
         1 100G             614        500        450 Loss                          50                 10 
         2 200A             615        300        650 Profit                       350             116.67 
         3 300A             616        100        111 Profit                        11                 11
*/
```

Comment: @kishore please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide some structured and reproducible sample data. We realy don't have time to do it for you. Or, even better, adjust the code above to work with your table/column names and structure.

Comment: Thankyou for giving reply some times table A have zero in the cost

Comment: TABLE A     
ITEM_ID,ITEM_TYPE,ITEM_COST,ITEM  
1,100F,1000,614  
1,100G,500,614  
2,200A,300,615  
2,200B,499,615  
3,300A,100,616  
4,400A,0,414          
TABLE B     
ITEM_ID,ITEM_TYPE,ITEM_COST,ITEM, P/l inrs, Profit / Loss in %
1,100F,500,614,500 rs loss,
1,100G,450,614,50 rs  loss, 
2,200A,650,615,350 rs  profit, 
3,300A,111,616,11 rs profit,

Comment: @kishore I just posted an addition...